# Allow access when certain query string exists otherwise deny

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to allow access to my site when there is `s=stick_path` or `s=stick_relative` in the query string otherwise deny the access. e.g allow access when `www.domain.com/?s=stick_path` but deny access when `www.domain.com/?s=ck_relative` or `www.domain.com/?s=action_path`.

I have tried for simple example like `www.domain.com/?s=stick_path` but it does not seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=stick_path$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I think one can trick the `.htaccess` rule if s parameter is present twice like `www.domain.com/?s=stick_path&s=action_path`

Answer (score 3):

The rules you have work for me when I try to go to `http://localhost/?s=stick_path`, but if you want to be able to check anywhere for the query string, try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=stick_path(&|$) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=stick_relative(&|$)
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

This works if either `s=stick_path` or `s=stick_relative` is anywhere in the querystring.

Comment: I didn't want to find anywhere in the string. It should be exact match.

Comment: @newbie if the query string must only be `s=stick_path`, then what you have already does that.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Answer pulled from an OP's update*</sup>

`RewriteEngine ON` was missing in the .htaccess.

So, the correct code was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=stick_path$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```